# Parameter 'pId' not found in the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void InsertSanalPos(int pCompanyId ,int pBankaId,string pMagazaNo,string pTerminalNo,string pKullaniciAdi,string pParola,string pSifre,string pTip,string pT9Text,string pNot,string pStatus,DateTime pRecordDate,string pGirisKodu)
{
    UtilMySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SpNameCollection.InsertBank,
            MySQLParameterGeneratorEx.GenerateParam(((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).GetParameters(),pCompanyId,pBankaId, pMagazaNo, pTerminalNo, pKullaniciAdi, pParola, pSifre, pTip, pT9Text, pNot, pStatus, pRecordDate, pGirisKodu));
}
```

Comment: That looks like a *horrible* API.

Comment: is value of field "columnname" in the current row, maybe you are not passing it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first clue here should be that `pId` only appears in the question title, and not in the parameters to the method or the parameters going down to the query; basically: yes, I think the message is entirely correct - there is no `pId` parameter, so if the SQL wants one, it is going to fail.